# c# class library trigger constructor to run function at interval

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class library which will be called in a asp.net application. Now I want to run a function at interval to get data from database. I want to use a static constructor to trigger the interval function. Is this idea workable?

The following is the draft code that I want to implement the above idea.

```
//This is one class that stays in the class library assembly.
public class UsageManager : IUsageManager
{
    static UsageManager()
    {
        //when the first time this class is called, it will run the function, and it will keep running non-stop to refresh the data periodically.
        RefreshData();
    }
}

public void RefreshData()  
{  
    try  
    {  
        this.timerObj = new Timer(LoadData, null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);  
        this.timerObj.Change(0, Timeout.Infinite);  
    }  
    catch (Exception ex)  
    {  
        //Log error     
    }  
}

private void LoadData(object state)  
{  
    try  
    {  
        TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.Now - this.lastUpdateTS;  
        if (elapsed.TotalMinutes >= this.refreshInterval)  
        {  
            // Load value from database     
            ProcessRecord();  
  
            this.lastUpdateTS = DateTime.Now;  
        }  
  
        // 6 seconds interval to call the method again..  
        this.timerObj.Change(6000, Timeout.Infinite);  
    }  
    catch (Exception ex)  
    {  
        // log exception    
    }  
}
```

Comment: So I guess you don't plan to unit test this class, because that static constructor will really paint you into a corner.

Comment: This generally sounds like a bad idea. Besides, static constructor is used to initializing static resources. However in your example you are calling an instance method, which is wrong ( not even compilable...) if you find that it is impossible to update the sample code then the answer is no.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? There are other option like schedulers windows and other which can be do this work.

Comment: @शेखर What I want to achieve is I want to load database table into dataset variables and then use the dataset to do linq query instead of access stored procedure each time. Thus reduce the access time to database. So to keep the dataset update, I need to update the dataset on interval.

Comment: @joe, Is there other way that I can update dataset variable periodically from loading database table into the dataset and let the dataset be used in linq query?

Comment: Seems good example for caching the data. Use the cache variable to store the data and on expiration fetch it from database. set the expiration time for as long as you want.

Comment: Here is [an example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/annathurai/data-cache-in-Asp-Net/) which may help you.

Comment: @शेखर Thanks. I will Cache instead.

Comment: But remember that you need a trigger point means when there is no data in cache and request comes at that time data will be fetched. or may very on implementation.

Comment: @want_to_be_calm I'm afraid you are asking an X/Y problem. I suggest you asking the real problem in a new topic instead of asking your "assumption" as a solution to your  problem, which can be misleading. And to answer your question, I would consider creating a seperate class to play as a DataProvider, and callers would fetch data from it. The data provider can implement caching mechanism.

Comment: @joe But is that suitable to explore the workable possibility of assumption in question? Because I am not sure whether the asumption works or not. So I need to have confirmation on the idea.

Comment: Which assumption do you mean? You seem to be presenting two distinct ideas for consideration; 1) having periodic background updates, and 2) using a static constructor as the initiator for that update cycle. For the first idea, it may or may not be appropriate, but it's hard to say without knowing more about your goals. A cache does seem more likely to be the way to go. As for the second idea, avoid it like the plague. If you insist on having a background update process, it would be much better to give the consumer of the class some degree of control over this process.